# Solving a differential equation with a function defined differently in different domains

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation of the form
$$
\frac{dV}{dt}+\frac{V}\tau=I
$$
where $I$ is given as
$$
I=\begin{cases}I_P\sin(\omega t),&\frac{2n\pi}{\omega}\le t\le \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{\omega} \\
-I_P\sin(\omega t),&\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{\omega} \lt t \le
\frac{2(n+1)\pi}{\omega}
\end{cases}
$$

where $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$

I can solve the differential equation by multiplying it by $e^{t/\tau}$ but I am unsure how to handle the multiple intervals of $I$.

The answer changes quite a lot once we make $I$ from a full sine to a rectified sine. What would be the way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to think about it if you specify the IVP you are solving, even symbolically, as in $V(t_0)=V_0$. Then you can multiply by $e^{t/\tau}$ as you say and then integrate, not indefinitely, but from $t_0$ to $t$:

$$\int_{t_0}^t \left ( e^{s/\tau} V(s) \right )' ds = e^{t/\tau} V(t) - e^{t_0/\tau} V(t_0) = \int_{t_0}^t I(s) ds.$$

Now you just split the integral on the right as required by the definition of $I$. This is not *that* bad because $I$ is periodic, so you can take "the number of completed periods times the integral over one period" and then add what's left over in the "current" period. It may still be easier to use the Laplace transform (a common technique for solving linear problems with piecewise forcing).

Answer (score 1):

Using the Laplace transform.

As $I(\omega,t,n) = I_0\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(\theta(t-k\frac{\pi}{\omega})-\theta(t-(k+1)\frac{\pi}{\omega}))\sin(\omega t)$ where $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside step function, we have

$$
\mathcal{L}\left[I(\omega,t,n)\right]=I_0\left(\left(\sum_{k=0}^n2 e^{-k\frac{\pi}{\omega}s}\right)-1-e^{-n\frac{\pi}{\omega}s}\right)\frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}
$$

and then

$$
V(s) = I_0\left(\left(\sum_{k=0}^n2 e^{-k\frac{\pi}{\omega}s}\right)-1-e^{-n\frac{\pi}{\omega}s}\right)\frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}\frac{\tau}{\tau s+1}+\frac{\tau V(0)}{\tau s + 1}
$$

so $V(t)$ can be easily obtained knowing $n$